# Using a django model method as static function

Tags: python, django, pandas, class, django-models

I would like to use a django model method as a static function. More specifically, I would like to use a model method called age, indicated below, both on an instance of my table Patient but I would also like apply the age function to a rows in a pandas dataframe using the pandas apply function. Is this possible to do or will I have to write another function specifically to work on my dataframe?

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    pat_id1 = models.AutoField(db_column='Pat_ID1', primary_key=True)  
    birth_dttm = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Birth_DtTm', blank=True, null=True)

    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Patient'

     @property
     def age(self):
         return relativedelta(date.today(), self.birth_dttm.date()).years
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `age` function is using `self`. This means this function is dependent on an instance of your class to give an output. So, this method cannot be declared as a `staticmethod`.

**EDIT**
Excerpt from [journaldev](https://www.journaldev.com/18722/python-static-method) Static methods have a very clear use-case. When we need some functionality not w.r.t an Object but w.r.t the complete class, we make a method static. This is pretty much advantageous when we need to create Utility methods as they aren’t tied to an object lifecycle.